# Dynamically create component in React and store it in state variable to show in Dialog

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-component, react-state-management, primereact

I am using PrimeReact to develop an application. In one of my React components, I am creating component dynamically using `React.createElement` and store it in a state variable. I am then showing that dynamically created component in a Dialog using PrimeReact. Below is the code to create component.

```
let element;
element = React.createElement(MyComponent, { ...props } ); // props defined earlier
this.setState({
   dynamicComponent: element,
   dialogVisible: true
});
```

Below is the code to show the `dynamicComponent` in a dialog.

```
<Dialog header="Form" visible={this.state.dialogVisible} style={{ width: '50vw' }} modal={true}>
    {this.state.dynamicComponent}
</Dialog>
```

The above code works only for the first time. The next time if I pass different `props`, it still shows component with previous `props`.

My questions are:

1. How can I make the dialog show the component with different props each time it is created?
2. Is this the right way to approach my problem? I also need to extend my solution so that it not just loads same component with different props, it also needs to load different component altogether.

Comment: Where do you do the setState?

Comment: @HMR: It's on click of a button.

Comment: Why is `element` inside of the state and not a component, in the render method, to which you pass those previously-defined props?

Comment: Where do props come from? My guess it's a stale closure. Can you post the click handler with the props part, right now it seems to come out of nowhere.